# How to have different levels of scroll speeds on a website

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I am trying to re-create an effect I made on my website. This effect consists of a repeating background that scrolls at a greater rate than the foreground. When I created this effect, I used a website builder and framework, but I am now in the process of trying to recreate everything on plain code, and I would like to know if this is possible.

Example Website: [www.migte.net](http://www.migte.net)

(To see the example effect, scroll down a bit and you will see text saying "Experience Flawless Quality" and if you scroll down a bit more, the effect repeats with lines in the background of a video)

How would I go about having a different scroll speed for the background than the rest of the page? I had tried one solution using web-kit transformations, but it didn't seem to work. Is this possible at all without using some sort of external framework / builder?

All help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what you are describing is called Parallax scrolling. Parallax scrolling is a web site trend where the background content (i.e. an image) is moved at a different speed than the foreground content while scrolling. - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp - a simple google search for "Parallax scrolling" will give you heaps of resources on how to do it and many examples of it in action

Comment: Okay, will look into it. Thanks!